# Named.conf error

Tags: dns, bind

i'm trying to configure a bind dns server on my CentOs.
So it failed to start for some reason , and when i'm runing a named-checkconfig
i get this output :

```
 /etc/named.conf:60: missing ';' before '.'
/etc/named.conf:60: unknown option '.'
/etc/named.conf:67: unexpected end of input
```

here is a named.conf file

```
/
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;10.0.0.20; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost;10.0.0.0; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "guayava.com" IN {
         type master;
         file "guayava.com.zone";
         allow-update { none; };
};
zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
         type master;
         file "guayava.com.rr.zone;
         allow-update { none; };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I will be grateful for any help.
PS. Sorry for noob question

Answer (score 0):

I assume your posted `named.conf` is an example, because `named-checkconf` shows line numbers 60 and 67, which is ways more than your example.

This appears to be a typo. did you close all open quotation marks and brackets, like `};`?

Comment: I have edited the named.conf file in the post . Actualy its not example , and i dont have idea why named.conf is not count the lines properly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved , it is unclosed Quotation Marks in reverse zone filename.

The service is running now